# For some reason the Subsidiary, entityid, payablesaccount, exoenseaccount are exporting the vaue of internal instead of the actual value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I am very new to Netsuite. I have the task of extracting the the Vendor in csv format to file cabinet. After searching on the internet I found a sample and tweaked it to what I want. However, after the export some fields like subsidiary is exporting with Internalid. I am not sure why. Please help me out with this.

function createFile(){

```
try{
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('vendor', 'customsearch_davoil_apx_vendor');
var csvBody = '';

if (searchResults == null || searchResults.length < 1) return;

for (var i=0; i<searchResults.length; i++){
  
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('subsidiary') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('entityid') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('subsidiary') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('companyname') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('address1') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('address2') + ',' ;
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('city') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('state') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('zipcode') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('country') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('terms') + ',';
" " + ',';
" " + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('phone') + ',';
" " + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue({name:'contact', join:'contactprimary'}) + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('currency') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('category') + ',';
csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue({name:'payablesaccount', join:'account'}) + ',';

csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue({name:'expenseaccount', join:'expaccount'}) + ',';

csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('isinactive') + '\n';

if( searchResults[i] == searchResults.length){
    csvBody += EOD|vd_mstr|Rowcount|searchResults.length;
    EOF

}

}

var file = nlapiCreateFile('APXPress_Vendor_${filename}_051820_081300.csv', 'CSV', csvBody);
file.setFolder('766');
nlapiSubmitFile(file);
}catch(e){

nlapiLogExecution('Error', 'createFile', 'Error while creating file - ' + e.message);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the fields you mentioned are `Select` fields (i.e. dropdown or list fields in the UI). In general these types of fields link from one record to another.

`Select` fields have two components: a `value` and a `text`. The `value` of a `Select` field is always the `internalid` of the selected record. The `text` is always the `name` of the selected record.

In a Search `Result` instance (i.e. your `searchResults[i]`), calling `getValue()` will return the `internalid` while calling `getText()` will return the `name`.

Wherever you want the display text from a List field, use `getText()` instead of `getValue()`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked very well. However, I have one more question.  How can i extract vendors linked to multiple subsidiary. I tried this join  csvBody += searchResults[i].getText('subsidiary','msesubsidiary'). But it not working.

Comment: Okay figured the issue. This is what i used to join csvBody += searchResults[i].getValue('namenohierarchy', 'msesubsidiary')